# Why can't I select all elements with an attribute value stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div data-id=5>...</div>
<img data-id=5 src=...>
<input data-id=5 ...>
...
```

I need to select and remove all elements with the attribute `data-id` equal to 5. My try:

```
var a = 5;
$('[data-id = a]').remove();
```

Doesn't work. Why doesn't it work and how do I fix it?

Comment: concat the var properly like `$('[data-id = '+a+']').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're sending "a" as a string literal and not a variable. Here's the correct way:

```js
var a = 5;
$('[data-id="' + a + '"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="5">...</div>
<input data-id="5" type="text" value="5"/>
<input data-id="4" type="text" value="4"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your **selector** is wrong used.

Try this:

```js
var a=5;
$('[data-id="'+a+'"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id=5>...</div>
<img data-id=5 src="">
<input data-id=5>
```

Comment: he has `var a=5`

Comment: @guradio, have a look now.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're *literally* selecting elements with the `data-id` attribute equal the `"a"` as it's part of the string literal. jQuery has no idea that `a` inside the string refers to the variable -- it has no way of knowing because it's a string *literal*. Instead, indicate that `a` is a variable and use it's value with string concatenation or interpolation:

```
$(`[data-id=${a}]`).remove()
```

Which is ES2015, or with string concatenation (if your browser or environment doesn't support it) which is functionally the same and what template literals actually desugar to:

```
$('[data-id=' + a + ']').remove()
```

This will use the value 5 stored in `a` to select elements where the `data-id` attribute is 5, not literally `"a"`.

Comment: what is difference between ES2015 and ES6 in concatenate case? 
Is it ES6 method is useful?

Comment: @PrashantTapase It's more clean IMO. It get's rid of the need for sometimes confusing operations. They both do exactly the same thing though. For example: `\`1 + 1 = ${1 + 1}\`` is cleaner than `'1 + 1 = ' + (1 + 1)'` IMO.

Comment: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id=${a}]`

Comment: @bonaca Probably the fact your browser doesn't support ES6. Use string concatenation instead, which is the exact same.

Comment: @what is mean by IMO? Ohh great example.

Comment: @PrashantTapase In my opinion.